# Build a multi os rpi build vm?

Tags: software-development

Want to set up a build vm for building multiple distros for rpi from scratch
raspian,pidora, arch - build my own customised remixes

Need minimal os images for use as sensor boards/sensorhubs and just want the minimal packages/libraries + our packages/programs/custom kernel modules(as required).

Used to using/building angstrom on older gumstix boards.
Are there any similar good build tools/scripts for raspian, pidora , arch etc ?

What would be the best way to set them up to be able to share sources

Any similar tutorials to openembedded/bitbake  http://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Getting_started
for building the different pi distros from scratch ?

For building own kernel modules better to stick with standard pi kernel or use adafruits modified version ?

Note I don't just want to customise my own images but build them from source for each distro.

All replies appreciated, thank you!

no tag for pidora yet ?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at my project Nard SDK. It has lots of your requested features;
it's minimal, intended for embedded systems and everything is built from sources.
http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/

Comments are most welcome!